# How to set up the FOUND_ROWS flag?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm using **Entity Framework 5**, **MySQL 5.6** and **MySQLConnector 6.6.5**.

I would like to set up the `FOUND_ROWS` flag in my Entity Framework connection string.

I tried the following configuration.

```
...
server=localhost;user id=root;option=2
..
```

According to the MySQL documentation the value '2' equals **FOUND_ROWS** parameter.

But it throws an **InvalidOperationException** saying that the **Keyword is not supported** (name parameter : option).

How am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
UseAffectedRows=false
```

[reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)

> UseAffectedRows
>
> When true, the connection reports changed rows instead of found rows.
>   This option was added in Connector/Net version 5.2.6.

Comment: Thank you. Next time I will read the documentation closer. I didn't know that there was two different names for this flag.

Comment: @Gonzalo Your reference link is dead. :(